# When inserting data in two tables in send table id is not insert but when i am inserting data second table id should inserted from first table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
Create Procedure Sp_instAdminmaster] 
(@Name varchar(20),@FatherName varchar(20),@Email_Id varchar(20),@Address nvarchar(100),@City varchar(20),@State varchar(20),@Qualification varchar(30),@contactNo varchar(10),@Date date,
    @Remarks varchar(150),@Type varchar(20),@Fee money,@ClassName nvarchar(20),@Yearly money,@Halfyearly1 money,
    @Halfyearly2 money,@Quaterly1 money,@Quaterly2 money,@Quaterly3 money,@Quaterly4 money,@January money,
    @February money,@March money,@April money,@May money,@June money,@July money,
    @August money,@September money,@October money,@November money,@December money)
        AS
BEGIN
Insert into AdmissionMaster(Name,FatherName,Email_Id,Address,City,State,Qualification,contactNo,Date,Remarks,Type,Fee,ClassName)
values (@Name,@FatherName,@Email_Id,@Address,@City,@State,@Qualification,@contactNo,
    @Date,@Remarks,@Type,@Fee,@ClassName);
declare @Id int 
Select @Id as Id  from  AdmissionMaster 

insert into tblAdmissionDetails(Id,Yearly,Halfyearly1,Halfyearly2,Quaterly1,Quaterly2,Quaterly3,Quaterly4,
    January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December)
    values(@Id,@yearly,@Halfyearly1,@Halfyearly2,@Quaterly1,@Quaterly2,@Quaterly3,@Quaterly4,@January,@February,@March,
    @April,@May,@June,@July,@August,@September,@October,@November,@December)
END
```

Comment: try this SET @Id= SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: Has AdmissionMaster table auto-incremented id ? Also `Select @Id as Id  from  AdmissionMaster` returns all id from table but not the last inserted. It might be done with `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for example

Comment: `Select @Id as Id` will just select the ID of whatever row it finds first in the table. It will not select the most recently inserted. As the others said, use SCOPE_IDENTITY(). P.S. It would have been trivial to find out how to do this by searching online...did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Select @Id as Id  from  AdmissionMaster
```

To

```
SELECT @Id=IDENT_CURRENT('AdmissionMaster');
```